# HighCharts xAxis show on 0 line with tick marks between all columns

Tags: highcharts

I've developed a bunch of bar charts in HighCharts cloud with positive and negative values.

First question:

- is it possible to have the xAxis appear at the 0 line (not at the bottom of the chart)?

What I've done so far is offset the xAxis so it's placed on the 0 line, which kinda works but I was hoping for a better solution. The other method I was think was to use plotLines code on the yAxis, but I don't get the ticks:

```
plotLines: [{
        color: '#010101',
        width: 2,
        value: 0,
        zIndex: 5
    }],
```

Second question:

- is it possible to have the tick marks to appear between each bar, and not just the bars that have an xAxis label?

This is what's rendering for me at the moment, and I'm trying to get a tick between all the bars while showing the same number of labels https://cloud.highcharts.com/show/cLtfEDClS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First question**: 
You can merge this configuration into chart options in Cloud’s custom code section:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var yAxis = this.yAxis[0];
        this.xAxis[0].update({
          offset: -yAxis.toPixels(Math.abs(yAxis.min), true)
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6712zrod/

It automatically positions x axis so that it works as `y = 0` line.

**Second question:**

Try setting `X Axis[0] > Labels > Step` to `1`.

[image]

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.step

**Explanation** from Docs:

*To show only every n'th label on the axis, set the step to n. Setting the step to 2 shows every other label.
By default, the step is calculated automatically to avoid overlap. To prevent this, set it to 1. This usually only happens on a category axis, and is often a sign that you have chosen the wrong axis type.*